# Error make marker when get lat and lng from JSON http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have some problem when i want marker some position with data lat and lng from http.get but when i use crome debugger show some error `setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`. i know the problem in my parse lat and lng but i don't know to fix it
this my JS

```
$scope.result = {};
                $http.get('http://192.168.100.13:88/OMG1/web.php?tN=find')
                  .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
                    console.log('data success');
                    console.log(data); // for browser console
                    $scope.result = data; // for UI
                  })
                  .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
                    console.log('data error');
                  })
                  .then(function(result){
                    things = result.data;
                  });

                $scope.findbtn = function () {
                    var mylatlng = {lat: $scope.result.latitude, lng: $scope.result.longitude};
                    //var mylatlng = {lat: $scope.myWelcome.index, lng: $scope.myWelcome.index};
                    //var mylatlng = {lat: -7.3342266, lng: 112.7650341};
                    //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($scope.result.latitude),parseFloat($scope.result.longitude));
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 1,
                        center: {lat: -7.3342266, lng: 112.7650341},
                        //center: {lat: data[0].lat, lng: data[0].lng},
                        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
                    });
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: mylatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Your Motor'
                    });
                    console.log(marker);
                };
```

and this data from `$scope.result.latitude` when i open in crome debugger `"-7.3342266"`. I don't know to fix lat from `"-7.3342266" to -7.3342266`
if you are have some idea please share and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse to float $scope.result.latitude

JS

```
$scope.findbtn = function () {
                    var lat = parseFloat($scope.result.latitude);
                    var lng = parseFloat($scope.result.longitude);
                    var mylatlng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
});
```